# Sending a goal to the Navigation stack from a ROS node

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i need  Sending a goal to the Navigation stack from a ROS node for wheeled_robot like this  example :
[Chefbot](http://apprize.info/programming/ros/10.html)

wheeled_robot :
[wheeled_robot](http://apprize.info/programming/ros/4.html)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247807/sending-a-goal-to-the-navigation-stack-from-a-ros-node/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

python code:

```
import rospy
import actionlib
from move_base_msgs.msg import MoveBaseAction, MoveBaseGoal
...
self.move_base = actionlib.SimpleActionClient("move_base", MoveBaseAction)
...
# Set up the goal location
self.goal = MoveBaseGoal()
self.goal.target_pose.pose = Pose(Point(0.643, 4.720, 0.000), Quaternion(0.000, 0.000, 0.223, 0.975))
self.goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = 'map'
self.goal.target_pose.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
...
self.move_base.send_goal(self.goal)
```

ref: https://github.com/pirobot/ros-by-example/blob/master/rbx_vol_1/rbx1_nav/nodes/nav_test.py

---

Originally posted by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) with karma: 287 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2